# Images become ugly when animated (CSS3 Transition)

Tags: html, css, firefox, transition

Since the new version of Firefox (29.0.1 on Mac OS 10.9.2) I see an unsightly effect on my CSS transitions. For example, if I animate the opacity of an image, during the transition, it will be very blury.

The following code shows the animations which I used.

```
a img {
    opacity: 0.8;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I have tried adding the following code, however it does not solve the problem

```
a:hover img{
    opacity : 1;
    transform : translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

http://ansoine.isondev.com/nav_test.html

Here is an image showing the blury effect that happends

[image: Blurry effect]

Comment: CAn you produce a jsfiddle?

Comment: If in the previous version it worked well, probably it's a bug. If you make a working demo, you can submit it to [bugzilla](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org).

Comment: Sure. Link added ;) http://ansoine.isondev.com/nav_test.html

Comment: @ThibautLamanthe There are no images in the webpage you linked

Comment: @Oriol No, but the bug is the same on the background

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can slightly make things better is removing the 'transparent' property of your icon  attributes. It is redundant and I think it reduces the quality a bit.

Your icons are very small, you can try converting them to SVG icons rather than raster PNGs.

Here is some guide on SVG icons from CSS-tricks.
http://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/

I guarantee you it is worth the effort. They will look much more sharper!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with Bootstrap Glyphicons. I fix ugliness by increasing font size.

Apparently glyphicons are store with big resolution, render it in a small size make them ugly.

```css
.bigger {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.icon-spin {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin{
    0%{transform:rotate(0deg)}
    100%{transform:rotate(359deg)}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


No animate - no sizing
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span><br>
Animate - no sizing
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh icon-spin"></span><br>
<hr>
No animate - with bigger size -> nicer
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh bigger"></span><br>
Animate - with bigger size -> nicer
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh bigger icon-spin"></span><br>
```